# How do I change the size of spinner items and height of spinner dropbox?

Tags: android

I am trying to increase the size of spinner items. I have taken an array called `SPINNERVALUES` in which I have declared all spinner items, I declared them in my XML file, so this may be the problem.

```
public class spinner extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner spinner;
String[] SPINNERVALUES = {"BVP","SINGHAD","MIT"};
String SpinnerValue;
Button GOTO;
Intent intent;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner);



        spinner =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        GOTO = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(spinner.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,SPINNERVALUES);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Adding setOnItemSelectedListener method on spinner.
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {

               SpinnerValue = (String)spinner.getSelectedItem();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        GOTO.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                switch(SpinnerValue) {

                    case "BVP":
                      intent = new Intent(spinner.this, CoverActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;

                    case "SINGHAD":
                        intent = new Intent(spinner.this, CoverActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;

                    case "MIT":
                        intent = new Intent(spinner.this, CoverActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

and my xml file is

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SUBMIT"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#3F51B5"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="81dp" />
```

Comment: what do you mean by "increase size of spinner item" ? Please elaborate

Comment: items in the spinner

Comment: String[] SPINNERVALUES = {"BVP","SINGHAD","MIT"};

Comment: aren't your spinner showing SPINNERVALUES ? Is it empty?

Comment: no,its working but I have to increase the size of my spinner items

Comment: You mean height and width of every single item, right ?

Comment: yes bro,please answer

Comment: I've added an answer, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Before your following code(setting up the adapter):

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Modify your dropdown item as your wish in - "simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml".
Sample:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#000000">
</TextView>
```

Hope this helps. :)